# Make pstricks ignore pictures

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I'm not even sure how to ask this

I'm interested in knowing if there is a way (a package option perhaps) to ignore the compilation of `pstricks` but leave the picture environment with its intended size. Somewhat like a debug mode to let me compile the whole document quickly only to test overlay and placement.

Does `pstricks` (and `pst-3dplot`) have an option to skip the contents of a **pspicture**?

I've checked the `.sty` file looking for clues but I might have missed it

Answer (score 1):

The version 2.64 of the main PSTricks package `pstricks.tex`: http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/
takes the `draft` option of the main documentclass into account:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
foo
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,3)
\psline{<->}(-2,-2)(3,3)
\end{pspicture}
bar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you can compile with the `auto-pst-pdf` package, which outsources `pspicture` environments to an auxiliary compilation. Once the environments are finalised, you can load `auto-pst-pdf` with the option `off`.